# Multivariate Central Limit Theorem for non-iid case

Tags: probability, statistics, convergence-divergence, central-limit-theorem, probability-limit-theorems

I already know about the classical Central Limit Theorem (CLT):

Let $X_1, \dots , X_n \in \mathbb{R}^d$ be the iid random variables drawn from a distribution with mean $\mu$ and covariance matrix $\Sigma$. Let $\displaystyle \bar{X} = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i = 1}^{n}{X_i}$ Then,
$$\sqrt{n}(\bar{X} - \mu) \rightsquigarrow \mathcal{N}(0, \Sigma). $$

But if we change the condition as $X_1, \dots, X_n \in \mathbb{R}^d$ are independent RVs but not identically distributed, the classical CLT result will not hold.

My question is:
For the multivariate independent but not identical RVs, does there exist any CLT (like the classical one) for them but without the triangular array assumption?

Comment: Check the multivariate Lindeberg Feller theorem. I don't have any reference though.

Comment: @WilliamM. Thanks. I find this theorem in this [note](http://personal.psu.edu/drh20/asymp/fall2006/lectures/ANGELchpt04.pdf). To be more clear, I modified the question. I wanna figure out that would be possible to say $C^{-\frac{1}{2}}_n \sum_{i=1}^{n}(X_i - \mu_i) \rightsquigarrow \mathcal{N}(0, I)$, where $C_n = \sum_{i=1}^{n} C_i$ is the sum of covariance matrice, like a high dimension version of "Lyapunov CLT".